# JUNIT test assert

Tags: java, testing, assert, junit5

I am trying to use JUNIT test for checking a URL that I used for parse.
I don't understand why I can not REPLACE this construction:

```
 @Test
    public void getHtmlPageExpectedExceptionTest() {
        try {
            siteParsingService.getHtmlPage("url");
            fail();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
        }
    }
```

With this one:

```
 @Test
    public void getHtmlPageExpectedExceptionTest() {
        assertNull(siteParsingService.getHtmlPage("url"));
    }
```

My method getHtmlPage in Class SiteParsingService(siteParsingService is  SiteParsingService's instance)looks like:

```
 @Nullable
    public Document getHtmlPage(String url) {
        Preconditions.checkArgument(url != null, "Url cannot be null");
        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            document.charset(StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
            return document;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.warn("Error while parsing url: '{}'", url);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Please, help!!!

Comment: Your test is expecting an `Exception` but your method only returns `null` on an `IOException`. FYI, you can use `assertThrows` to ensure an exception is thrown

Comment: Also, your question is unclear... _"why cant i REPLACE this construction?"_. So what happens if you do?